# trying to take sql data and then define just one of the rows in a php variable

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Hi I have the details of two car drivers getting pulled from a database but then I want to just grab one of the two and echo it out in php. I am able to take both drivers details and echo them both out using a while loop but not target just one of them:

By using the code below I echo out both records. Is there a way to just grab one of them?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 


{
echo "A driver:<br />";
echo "Name:". $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']."<br />"; 
echo "Latitude:". $row['CoordLat']."<br />"; 
echo "Longitude:". $row['CoordLong'];


$driverlat = $row['CoordLat'];
$driverlong = $row['CoordLong'];



}//end of while loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `while` loop ?

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

echo "A driver:<br />";
echo "Name:". $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']."<br />"; 
echo "Latitude:". $row['CoordLat']."<br />"; 
echo "Longitude:". $row['CoordLong'];

$driverlat = $row['CoordLat'];
$driverlong = $row['CoordLong'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a while loop at all.

Just do `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` on it's own separate line.
This will display the first row result.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a `break;` at the end of the while loop. Then only the first row is processed.

Better way would be to use no loop: Just assign the `$row` and do the render stuff.

Comment: cool but say there were 5 results and I wanted to grab the third one id there a way to do that?

Comment: @Paul: Maybe simplify your `query` so it only returns the 1 result that you want?